# How to retrieve certs from windows certstore by serial number?

Tags: winapi, cryptoapi

I am trying to retrieve a random certificate from the windows cert store, in this case a common Digicert root cert (this is only for testing). I modified some of the sample code I could find, but can't get it to work.

I am suspecting I may be encoding the search parameters wrong.The MSDN documentation is not very useful here, is issuer a SBCS or unicode string? Do I pass the issuer name, or the string as a fully qualified issuer (CN, OU, O, C, etc)? What else am I doing wrong?

The following is my fully self-contained test app, and therefore it's not "pretty", and doesn't have much error handling in place:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>

void panic(const char* s);
int main(void)
{
    #define MY_ENCODING_TYPE  (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING)

    HCERTSTORE      hSystemStore;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT  pTargetCert = NULL;

    if (!(hSystemStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, 
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Root")))
        panic("Error opening the Root store.");

    CERT_NAME_BLOB issuer;
    CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB serial;

    const char* issuer_str = "DigiCert Global Root CA";
    const char* sn_string = "083be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a";

    serial.cbData = (DWORD)strlen(sn_string) / 2;
    serial.pbData = new BYTE[serial.cbData];

    const char* pos = sn_string;
    for (size_t count = 0; count < serial.cbData; count++) {
        sscanf_s(pos, "%2hhx", &serial.pbData[count]);
        pos += 2;
    }

    issuer.cbData = (DWORD)strlen(issuer_str);
    issuer.pbData =  (BYTE *)issuer_str;

    CERT_ISSUER_SERIAL_NUMBER  findparams;
    findparams.Issuer = issuer;
    findparams.SerialNumber = serial;

    CERT_ID id;
    id.dwIdChoice = CERT_ID_ISSUER_SERIAL_NUMBER;
    id.IssuerSerialNumber = findparams;

    if (!(pTargetCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hSystemStore,           // Store handle.
        MY_ENCODING_TYPE,       // Encoding type.
        0,                      // Not used.
        CERT_FIND_CERT_ID,// Find type. Find a string in the 
        // certificate's subject.
        &id,          // The string to be searched for.
        pTargetCert)))           // Previous context.
        panic("Could not find the required certificate");

    if (pTargetCert)
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pTargetCert);
    if (hSystemStore)
    {
        if (!CertCloseStore(
            hSystemStore,
            CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG))
            panic("Could not close the certificate store");
    }
}

void panic(const char* s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error number %x.\n", s, GetLastError());
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What is the return value of the CertFindCertificateInStore function? If the return value is NULL, I suggest you could try to call GetLastError for extended error information.

Comment: The blobs need to be [encoded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencodeobjectex).

Comment: The result from the function was just that the cert was not found. The answer by RbMm was invaluable and solved the issue, the documentation is very poor. It all came down to encoding the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `CERT_NAME_BLOB Issuer` must be encoded, but not point to plain text name. you can use here or `CryptEncodeObjectEx` with `X509_NAME` and filled `CERT_NAME_INFO` as input. or use `CertStrToNameW`

and need use full name - `"C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root CA"`

then string `"083be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a"` must be reversed ( it shown in certificate properties in reverse byte order, unlike say *Thumbprint*)

the working code:

```
void reverse(PBYTE pb, size_t cb )
{
    if (cb)
    {
        PBYTE qb = pb + cb;

        do 
        {
            BYTE b = *--qb;
            *qb = *pb;
            *pb++ = b;
        } while (pb < qb);
    }
}

HRESULT FindCert(_Out_ PCCERT_CONTEXT* ppTargetCert, _In_ PCWSTR issuer_str, _In_ PCWSTR sn_string )
{
    CERT_ID id = { CERT_ID_ISSUER_SERIAL_NUMBER }; 

    while (CryptStringToBinaryW(sn_string, 0, CRYPT_STRING_HEXRAW, 
        id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.pbData, &id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.cbData, 0, 0))
    {
        if (id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.pbData)
        {
            reverse(id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.pbData, id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.cbData);

            while (CertStrToNameW(X509_ASN_ENCODING, issuer_str, CERT_X500_NAME_STR|CERT_NAME_STR_COMMA_FLAG, 0, 
                id.IssuerSerialNumber.Issuer.pbData, &id.IssuerSerialNumber.Issuer.cbData, 0))
            {
                if (id.IssuerSerialNumber.Issuer.pbData)
                {
                    if (HCERTSTORE hSystemStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, 
                        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE|CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG|CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG, 
                        L"root"))
                    {
                        ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

                        if (PCCERT_CONTEXT pTargetCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(hSystemStore, 
                            X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_CERT_ID, &id, 0))
                        {
                            *ppTargetCert = pTargetCert;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dwError = GetLastError();
                        }

                        CertCloseStore(hSystemStore, 0);

                        return dwError;
                    }

                    break;
                }

                if (0x400 < id.IssuerSerialNumber.Issuer.cbData)
                {
                    return RPC_S_STRING_TOO_LONG;
                }

                id.IssuerSerialNumber.Issuer.pbData = (PBYTE)alloca(id.IssuerSerialNumber.Issuer.cbData);
            }

            break;
        }

        if (0x100 < id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.cbData)
        {
            return RPC_S_STRING_TOO_LONG;
        }

        id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.pbData = (PBYTE)alloca(id.IssuerSerialNumber.SerialNumber.cbData);
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

    PCCERT_CONTEXT pTargetCert;
    if (NOERROR == FindCert(&pTargetCert, 
        L"C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root CA", 
        L"083be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a"))
    {
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pTargetCert);
    }
```